# MySQL ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'mysql_old_password' is not loaded on MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, plugins, passwords, homebrew

After running the following commands (in an attempt to fix something else)

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_old_password'
mysql> WHERE User = 'some_user' AND Host = 'some_host';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR
    -> 'some_user'@'some_host' = OLD_PASSWORD('new_password');
```

I haven't been able to run mysql using `mysql -u root` as it gives me the error `Plugin 'mysql_old_password' is not loaded`. I have tried reinstalling mysql using homebrew and even removing some mysql folders using rm -rf and following other stack overflow posts.

**EDIT:**
I am using `mysql version 8.0.30 for macOS 12.4`
When I run `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables` I get the error `sudo: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: command not found`.

And when I simply run `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` I get

```
[1] 51759
my-username@Macbook-Pro ~ % 
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Comment: You should be able to restart mysqld without password checking so you can reset the password.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that? Running "sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &" isn't working for me

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a mysql server admin. If you ask in [dba.se] you may be able to get the help you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was given the following post on GitHub to properly uninstall MySQL so that I could reinstall it again and have it work correctly: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d

[image: GitHub Post by VitorBritto to properly uninstall MySQL]

[image: A comment on that post to properly uninstall MySQL on Apple Silicon devices]

Comment: Especially, `rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql`